# animate to active item on tab panel in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

My system has 2 views: Login and Account.The Account view is a Tab Panel that has 5 tabs.If users log into system successful, system will show second tab of Account view. I had tried many ways to do this but all of them are not working.The event is written in the Controller.

In login action:

```
if (loginSuccess) {
    this.redirectTo("account");
}
```

In the define of route account, I write 3 ways.
First way:

```
var view = this.getAccountView();
view.setActiveTab(1);
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(view, {type:'slide'});
```

Second way:

```
var view = this.getAccountView();
view.animateActiveItem(1, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
```

Third way:

```
var view = this.getAccountView();
view.setActiveItem(1);
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(view, {type:'slide'});
```

All of them are go to "First tab" not "Second tab". Is anyone knows it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the ref is well pointed, it should work with:

```
this.getAccountView().setActiveItem(1);
```